# Regex that separates hexadecimal color code from CSS Code - Non Trivial Cases

Tags: python, css, regex, colors

I am trying to separate out all the color codes used inside the CSS code using regex.
Given below is a sample CSS code:

```
#ffffff
{
    color: #cccaaa; background-color:#abcdef;
    font-size: 123px;
    text = "fff";
}

#ABC
{
    background-color:#123456
}
```

Here, the color codes are #cccaaa, #abcded and #123456. But #ffffff and #ABC are not color codes here.

The regex that I am using is:
`\b(?=((?:#?[\da-fA-F]{3}){1,2})[^\w][;\s]*)\b`

I want to improve my regex. In order to improve, I want to know all the CSS Properties that support Hex Color Codes.

I found some of them like:

background-color, color and border-color. Is this all or am I missing something. I think I can use the word 'color:' to better my regex.

Please help me list all the properties that support hex color codes or help me better my regex.

Comment: There's an easier way. I can write regex to only check for those colors if they are between an open and closing bracket if you'd like. Would that work?

Comment: 'Hex,' in HTML/CSS colour-codes, means '[hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)' (base-16), not 'hexagonal.' Incidentally, you're missing all the properties that can accept a short-hand list of properties including colours, such as `border: width style color`, `box-shadow: xOffset yOffset blurDistance spread color`...

Comment: @DavidThomas. Sorry and thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Flipybitz that would work too :D but then we have to take care of inline CSS too. like `#ffffff { color: #abcded; }`

Comment: It should work with that too, don't worry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, prepare yourself...

`\:(?:(?!(?:\;|\n|\r))[\w\W])*?\#((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3}){1,2})(?:(?!(?:\;|\n|\r))[\w\W])*?(?:\;|\n|\r)` should work.

UPDATED: Okay, NOW it should work. Instead of my original solution checking between brackets, it now checks between a `:` and either a `;` or the end of a line. Inside of that check it'll check for a valid hexadecimal color and capture it (The middle part of the code, the `#((?:[A-f0-9]{3}){1,2})` portion is the part to capture the colors, you may moddify this as you please).

The outcome will look something like this:

[image]

Hope this works! If not let me know and I'll see what I can do to get it to work for your case.

Comment: Use character range `[a-fA-F0-9]` instead of `[A-f0-9]`. To see why, try this: `"".join(re.findall(r'[A-f]', string.ascii_letters))`. The range `[A-f]` includes the upper case characters `[H-Z]`.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT: I was using a tricky shorthand `[^]` to select everything, but this was throwing weird errors. I've updated the answer to use `[\w\W]` instead, which should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would only look for hex values inside brackets `{ }`

Doing it in two steps and using a for loop makes your regex much more readable, and makes it possible to be context-sensitive in a way that is not possible, or at best really hard, using just a monolithic regular expression.

```
css = """
#ffffff {
    color: #cccaaa; background-color:#abcdef;
    font-size: 123px;
    text = "fff";
}

#ABC {
    background-color:#123456
}
"""
import re
inside_brackets = re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', css, flags=re.DOTALL)
for attributes in inside_brackets:
    print(re.findall(r'#(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\b', attributes))
```

output:

```
['#cccaaa', '#abcdef']
['#123456']
```

Comment: Wouldn't this match something like `{random stuff here #dad}` ?

Comment: Yes, but that would not be valid css anyway.

Comment: It would be if it was quoted out. It'd still get matched if it was `{/* stuff #dad */}`

Comment: Yes. If you don't want comments to be included in the search, you should just strip them from the input first, before running the regex. Don't try to do everything in a huge regular expression. When the regex is as short as mine, you could easily see that it would match comments. With the currently accepted answer, these kinds of edge-cases are hard to catch when writing the code, and might lead to extremely hard-to-debug problems in production.